# How to compare XQuery output with databasein SOAP UI

Tags: soap, soapui

I have written Xquery assertion in SOAP UI request its working fine. But i want to compare output of this with database. Can I add code to get the values from database in Expected panel of XQuery assertion of SOAP UI. If not is there any way where I can compare the xml response of a request with column values of a database

Comment: You may use groovy script to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

1. Call a service with a Soap request
2. Make a property transfer from the service response to a test case variable, see the [SoapUI docs for more information](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html). You can use XPath or XQuery. See the picture bellow.

[image: Property Transfer]

3. Make a [JDBC request to your database](https://www.soapui.org/jdbc/getting-started.html) and compare the results with the data stored in your test case variable.

This way is intuitive and effective for simple comparissons, for complex tests I would choose Groovy scripting.